# Zeta function double product

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Is it possible to write the following double product in terms of the zeta function?

\begin{align}
&\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-(p_i\  p_j)^{-s}}
\end{align}

Extending the zeta function to semiprimes with

\begin{align}
&\prod _{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1 -\ q_{i}^{\ \ -s}}\\
\end{align}

where $q$ runs through the semiprimes is rewritable as

\begin{align}
&\left( \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-(p_i\  p_j)^{-s}}\right)^{1/2}\left( \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-(p_i{^2})^{-s}}\right)^{1/2}
\end{align}

The last part can clearly be rewritten as $\zeta(2s)^{1/2}$, but I don't know how I can rewrite the first part in terms of the zeta function.

In addition, I believe it may be that the triprime zeta function

\begin{align}
&\prod_{\Omega(q)=3}^{}\dfrac{1}{1 -\ q^{\ -s}}\\
\end{align}

can be written

\begin{align}
&\left(\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-(p_i\  p_j\ p_k)^{-s}}\right)^{1/6}\left( \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-(p_i^{\ 2}\  p_j)^{-s}}\right)^{1/2}\left( \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-(p_i{^3})^{-s}}\right)^{1/3}
\end{align}

and the function

\begin{align}
&\prod_{\Omega(q)=4}^{}\dfrac{1}{1 -\ q^{\ -s}}\\
\end{align}

can be written

\begin{align}
&\left(\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \prod_{l=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-(p_i\  p_j\ p_k\ p_l)^{-s}}\right)^{1/24}
\left(\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-(p_i^{\ 2}\  p_j\ p_k)^{-s}}\right)^{1/4}\\
&\left( \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-(p_i^{\ 3}\  p_j)^{-s}}\right)^{1/3}
\left( \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-(p_i^{\ 2}\  p_j^{\ 2})^{-s}}\right)^{1/8}
\left( \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-(p_i{^4})^{-s}}\right)^{1/4}
\end{align}

which of course presents the greater problem of defining the further multiple products in terms of the zeta function.

Comment: Any particular reason why this product is being considered?

Comment: @TerryTao I am studying the semiprime counting function. I will update the post accordingly.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Doesn't look very promising, as there does not appear to be an Euler product factorisation.  I think you're better off working with the second von Mangoldt function $\Lambda_2(n) = \Lambda(n) \log n + \Lambda*\Lambda(n)$ to count semiprimes (note that $\sum_n \frac{\Lambda_2(n)}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta''(s)}{\zeta(s)}$).

Comment: @TerryTao If you have time, I would be really grateful if you could take a look at the products post revisions. I am fairly sure I have removed the errors now. 

The initial confusion on my part was due, I think, to an error converting the semiprime reciprocal sum

\begin{align}
&\sum_{\Omega(n)=2}^{}\dfrac{1}{n^{s}}=\frac{1}{2} \sum _{j=1}^{\infty}\sum _{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(p_i\  p_j)^{s}}+\frac{1}{2} \sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(p_k{^2})^{s}}
\end{align}

(which I am almost certain is correct) to a product. I am fairly sure things are fixed now.

Comment: @martin, just to clarify, are you implying that $\sum_{\Omega(n)=2}\frac{1}{n^s}=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-(p_{i}p_{j})^{-s}}$?

Comment: @A.Neves No - consider \begin{align} &\sum_{\Omega (n)=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}=\sum_{\text{prime }p}^{}\frac{1}{p^{s}}\neq \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-p_i^{-s}} \end{align}

Comment: Try and express the infinite product as an infinite series, similar to that of the [Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: @Lucian Thanks for the comment - I tried to do that [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/199001/experimentation-with-partial-euler-products) - unsuccessfulkly though I'm afraid. Is there a better approach I should be taking?

Comment: @martin: [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2017_February_22#Three_.CE.B6-like_Products).

Comment: @Lucian thanks for the link - yes, that seems like a better approach. Not quite sure what he means by `when you play the game you pick up a coefficient counting the number of factorizations of n as a product of powers of semiprimes` at the moment, but I'll have a play around with it when I have more time.

Comment: @martin: He is probably referring to finding an adequate semi-prime equivalent for the $\Omega$ function. (Which might be easier said than done, but it definitely constitutes a valid approach).

Comment: @Lucian wouldn't that only cover numbers with an even number of prime factors?

Comment: @martin: I am leaning in a similar direction myself, but, then again, I also thought that the product over semi-primes and the double product over primes were one and the same, plus the other blunder I mentioned in the linked article. My spider sensors are a bit off right now, I'm afraid.